# How to display dates (eg. 01/10/2015) instead of days (eg. Monday, Tuesday) in my timetable

Tags: java, android, datetime, google-calendar-api

My table only can display days. I want to display dynamic dates instead of days activities.How can I display it. Here is my codes for days activities:

```
   protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        //close the progress dialog
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        //initialize the View
        if ((res1 != null) && (res1.getHttpCode() == 200)) {

            ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) timetable.findViewById(R.id.pager_day);

            String res = res1.getBody();           

            week = new Gson().fromJson(res, ExamWeeklyTimetable.class );

            if ((week.getMondayActivities().size() == 0) && (week.getTuesdayActivities().size() == 0) &&
                    (week.getWednesdayActivities().size() == 0) && (week.getFridayActivities().size() == 0) &&
                    (week.getThursdayActivities().size() == 0) && (week.getSaturdayActivities().size() == 0) &&
                    (week.getSundayActivities().size() == 0)) {
                RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) timetable.findViewById(R.id.semesterDay);
                rl.removeAllViews();
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                rl.addView(View.inflate(timetable.getContext(), R.layout.fragment_layout_timetable_fail, null), params);
             } else 
            {
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
     //                    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
     //                    int date = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                pager.setAdapter(buildAdapter(res));
                if (day == 1) {
                    int finalDay = 6;
                    pager.setCurrentItem(finalDay);
                } else {
                    int finalDay = day - 2;
                    pager.setCurrentItem(finalDay);
                }

                pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(7);
            }
```

Below here is the class for ExamWeeklyTimetable.java

```
   package com.tp.cis.mobile.ExamTimetable;

  import java.util.List;

  import com.tp.cis.mobile.Classes.Activity;

  public class ExamWeeklyTimetable {
 String AcademicYear;
    List<Activity> MondayActivities;
    List<Activity> TuesdayActivites;
    List<Activity> WednesdayActivities;
    List<Activity> ThursdayActivities;
    List<Activity> FridayActivities;
    List<Activity> SaturdayActivities;
    List<Activity> SundayActivities;
    List<Activity> WholeWeekActivities;
    String SemesterName;

    public String getAcademicYear() {
        return AcademicYear;
    }

    public void setAcademicYear(String academicYear) {
        this.AcademicYear = academicYear;
    }

    public List<Activity> getMondayActivities() {
        return MondayActivities;
    }

    public void setMondayActivities(List<Activity> mondayActivities) {
        this.MondayActivities = mondayActivities;
    }

    public List<Activity> getTuesdayActivities() {
        return TuesdayActivites;
    }

    public void setTuesdayActivities(List<Activity> tuesdayActivities) {
        this.TuesdayActivites = tuesdayActivities;
    }

    public List<Activity> getWednesdayActivities() {
        return WednesdayActivities;
    }

    public void setWednesdayActivities(List<Activity> wednesdayActivities) {
        this.WednesdayActivities = wednesdayActivities;
    }

    public List<Activity> getThursdayActivities() {
        return ThursdayActivities;
    }

    public void setThursdayActivities(List<Activity> thursdayActivities) {
        this.ThursdayActivities = thursdayActivities;
    }

    public List<Activity> getFridayActivities() {
        return FridayActivities;
    }

    public void setFridayActivities(List<Activity> fridayActivities) {
        this.FridayActivities = fridayActivities;
    }

    public List<Activity> getSaturdayActivities() {
        return SaturdayActivities;
    }

    public void setSaturdayActivities(List<Activity> saturdayActivities) {
        this.SaturdayActivities = saturdayActivities;
    }

    public List<Activity> getSundayActivities() {
        return SundayActivities;
    }

    public void setSundayActivities(List<Activity> sundayActivities) {
        this.SundayActivities = sundayActivities;
    }

    public List<Activity> getWholeWeekActivities() {
        return WholeWeekActivities;
    }

    public void setWholeWeekActivities(List<Activity> wholeWeekActivities) {
        this.WholeWeekActivities = wholeWeekActivities;
    }

    public String getSemesterName() {
        return SemesterName;
    }

    public void setSemesterName(String semesterName) {
        this.SemesterName = semesterName;
    }
```

}

Comment: Please search StackOverflow before posting.

Comment: Please suggest me an answers before comment

Comment: @kkyawmyohtet01 One of the many duplicate Questions is linked as part of closing this question. Look up near the top for that link, if reading this on a web page. You’ll find answers there and on similar Questions. Look for more "Related Questions" on the right, if viewing this on a web page. And again, please search before posting (Search box upper-right). Duplicates degrade the value of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the date in a format make a method like that and call that method in your date picker dialog box

```
private void updateLabel() 
{
    String myFormat = "MM/dd/yy"; //In which formt you need put here
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);

   // JoiningDate.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
}
```

Hope it helps ...

Answer (score 0):

Add this

```
 Date d = new Date(year, month, day);
 SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "MM-dd-yyyy");
 strDate = dateFormatter.format(d);
```